# Classes Point, Line - multiClasses?

Tags: python, class

I've this exercise. I'm given with the classes `Line` and `Point`. I've to find the slope of the line and if the point is on the line. But my problem is that I've two classes and the `def isonline` needs all the attributes `x,y,a,b,c`. So this is what I've done. Any thoughts how I can fix that?

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
class Line:
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        self.c=c
    def slope(self):
        try:
            return -self.a/self.b
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            return None
    def isonline(self,Point):
        if (self.a*self.x+self.b*self.y+self.c)==0:
            return True
        else:
            return False


coordinatesPoint=Point(4,1)
abcfromLine=Line(10,2,1)

print abcfromLine.slope()
print abcfromLine.isonline(coordinatesPoint)
```

Comment: Whats the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `Point.x`,`Point.y` would solve your problem.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
class Line:
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        self.c=c
    def slope(self):
        try:
            return -self.a/self.b
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            return None
    def isonline(self, point):
        if (self.a*point.x+self.b*point.y+self.c)==0:
            return True
        else:
            return False


coordinatesPoint=Point(4,1)
abcfromLine=Line(10,2,1)

print abcfromLine.slope()
print abcfromLine.isonline(coordinatesPoint)
```

BTW I prefer using lowercase as parameters.